# Npgsql.dll doesn't work in host

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, dll, npgsql

I am developing website  using asp.net,NetFramework 4.5, mssql. I added npgsql.dll via nuget package manager for connect to postgresql database in remote server. Everthing worked in my local machine  but didn't work in host.

```
public static string IsConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection Conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Npgcstring);
            //Conn.Open();

            return "DB success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message + "DB Catch";
        }         
    }
```

return :"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.DB Catch" 
I tried NpgsqlException and SqlException instead of Exception but it didn't trigger catch , it returned  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in page and I wrote :

```
var Conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Npgcstring);
```

instead of:

```
 NpgsqlConnection Conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Npgcstring);
```

return same exception.

Note: Only Npgsql.dll's code  didn't work , other codes worked in host which I got

We contact  company which we got hosting. They said "There are no restrictions".
I tried  another server which give free hosting , everything  worked.
Have you encountered such a problem?

Edit:

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return  "DB Catch::" + FullException(ex);
            }



public static string FullException(Exception exception)
        {

            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (exception != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(exception.Message);
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(exception.StackTrace);
                exception = exception.InnerException;
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

result:

```
DB Catch::Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool..ctor(NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, String connString)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetPoolAndSettings()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at DAL.DB.IsConnection()
```

Comment: You need to post the full exception, including the stack trace, for anyone to understand what's going.

Comment: I just added full exception.

Comment: Can you please confirm which exact Npgsql version you're using (should be 3.2.2)?

Comment: Npgsql 3.2.2 , Yes, I installed via Package Manager Console(Install-Package Npgsql)